# Show all the combinations of exploding dice

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, probability, dice

I am trying to evaluate the effectiveness of different units in a tabletop game (Mantic's Deadzone, for anyone who is interested) that uses exploding eight-sided dice (D8). For example, a player rolls `3D8`; for each die that shows an `8`, the player is allowed to roll an additional `D8`, and can continue to do so ad *infinity*.

Not being a mathematician, I decided on a brute-force approach, and have created a recursive function in **C#** that writes all the possible combinations of dice rolls (up to a certain number of additional dice - represented by the max_generations variable -, after which the probabilities become too small to be significant).

```
    class Program
    {
        private int dice_faces = 8;
        private int max_generations = 5;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().GenerateRoll(new List<int>() { 1 });
        }
        private List<int> GenerateRoll(List<int> dice)
        {
            if (dice == null || dice.Count == 0) 
                return new List<int>();

            if (dice[dice.Count - 1] == dice_faces)
            {
                if (dice.Count < max_generations)
                {
                    dice.Add(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", dice));
                    dice = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", dice));
                dice[dice.Count - 1]++;
            }

            return GenerateRoll(dice);
        }
    }
```

This function *works well* when starting with a *single dice* as in the example above, but it *does not generate the full range* of possible rolls when starting with multiple dice (i.e. `new Program().GenerateRoll(new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1 }););` it only shows the rolls for the *last dice* in the list.

I would be grateful for any assistance with updating the function to work with any number of starting dice.

**edited to include sample expected output (showing generations of exploding dice)**

```
2 dice, 3 faces, 4 generations

1 G1, 1 G1
1 G1, 2 G1
1 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2
1 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2
1 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 1 G3
1 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 2 G3
1 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G4
1 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G4
1 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
2 G1, 1 G1
2 G1, 2 G1
2 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2
2 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2
2 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 1 G3
2 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 2 G3
2 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G4
2 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G4
2 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 1 G1, 1 G2
3 G1, 1 G1, 2 G2
3 G1, 1 G1, 3 G2, 1 G3
3 G1, 1 G1, 3 G2, 2 G3
3 G1, 1 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 1 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 1 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 2 G1, 1 G2
3 G1, 2 G1, 2 G2
3 G1, 2 G1, 3 G2, 1 G3
3 G1, 2 G1, 3 G2, 2 G3
3 G1, 2 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 2 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 2 G1, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 1 G2
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 2 G2
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 1 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 1 G2
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 2 G2
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 2 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3, 1 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3, 2 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3, 3 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3, 3 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 1 G3, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3, 1 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3, 2 G3
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3, 3 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3, 3 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 2 G3, 3 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 1 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G3, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G3, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 2 G3, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 1 G4, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 1 G4, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 1 G4, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 2 G4, 1 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 2 G4, 2 G4
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 2 G4, 3 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 3 G4, 1 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 3 G4, 2 G4 # max generation reached
3 G1, 3 G1, 3 G2, 3 G2, 3 G3, 3 G3, 3 G4, 3 G4 # max generation reached
```

Comment: If you know 1ED8 (one exploding D8 :p), you're done: 3ED8 = 1ED8 + 1ED8 + 1ED8.

Comment: "*but it does not work*" is not a technical description of a problem

Comment: *"This function works well when starting with a single dice as in the example above"* Does it really? When I run the code above, the output makes no sense to me. What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: @RufusL: the output shows each of the possible rolls, starting with a single eight-sided dice, and including the rolls for additional dice if the previous dice rolls an 8.

Comment: But for every added die, the output always shows a bunch of `8`'s followed by a different number. I'm running your code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dUvYJl). Does the output match what you are seeing?

Comment: @RufusL: that is correct. The player rolls a D8. The first 7 rows represent this D8 showing results 1 to 7. If the player rolls an 8, they immediately roll a second D8, meaning rows 7-14 represent the second D8 showing results 1 to 7. If the player rolls an 8 on the second dice, they immediately roll a third D8, and so on. The issue I have is that the initial roll should be 3 dice, not 1, meaning the first rows should be: 1 1 1, 1 1 2, 1 1 3, 1 1 4, 1 1 5, 1 1 6, 1 1 7, 1 1 8 1, 1 1 8 2, etc.

Comment: I meant rows 8-14, not 7-14, sorry!

Comment: Ok, I guess I don't understand how you're consuming the data in that format, but maybe I don't need to know! :) If you want to output numbers for more than one die, I suspect you'll need to create a `for` or `foreach` loop over the `dice` array and return the output in a `List<List<int>>` (a list of lists). Maybe a good place to start is writing it for a normal set of dice (ignoring the `8` rule). Then when that's working, it may be easier to modify it for the special case.

Comment: @RufusL: that was my initial thought, but I would like to be able to support a variable number of starting dice, meaning I cannot hardcode a set number of for/foreach loops. I found it relatively trivial to write a program that shows all the possible dice rolls without the exploding-8 rule, but this rule is the key issue that has gotten me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the problem, we will have all possible dice rolls be represented by an encoding from

`0` (roll only ones) to `faces ^ dies - 1` (roll all eights).
E.g., for two 8-sided dies (0 to 63).

We then just convert every encoded to a new base of `faces` (base 8 for 8-sided dies)

```
IEnumerable<int[]> GenerateRoll(int dies, int dice_faces)
{
    var allFaces = Enumerable.Range(1, dice_faces).ToArray();
    var allOnes = Enumerable.Repeat(1, dies);

    var count = (int)Math.Pow(dice_faces, dies);

    return
        Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(roll => ToBaseX(roll, dice_faces, allFaces, allOnes.ToArray()));                    
}

int[] ToBaseX(long value, int baseValue, int[] target, int[] buffer)
{
    var i = buffer.Length;

    do
    {
        buffer[--i] = target[value % baseValue];
        value = value / baseValue;
    }
    while (value > 0);

    return buffer;
}
```

Well, that wasn't too bad.
Now if we want exploding dies, we choose to generate a new roll sequence of 1 die roll for every exploding die present (the `Where` condition)

```
IEnumerable<(int gen, int value)[]> GenerateRoll(int dies, int faces, int max_generations, int gen = 1)
{
    if (max_generations == gen)
        return Enumerable.Empty<(int, int)[]>();

    var allFaces = Enumerable.Range(1, faces).ToArray();
    var allOnes = Enumerable.Repeat(1, dies);

    return
         Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Pow(faces, dies))
        .Select(roll => ToBaseX(roll, faces, allFaces, allOnes.ToArray()))
        .Select(roll => roll.Select(value => (gen, value)).ToArray())
        .SelectMany(roll =>
        {
            var explosions = roll.Count(r => r.value == faces);

            if (explosions == 0)
                return new[] { roll };

            return GenerateRoll(explosions, faces, max_generations, gen + 1) //roll explosion dies
                   .Select(last => roll.Concat(last).ToArray()); //the new roll gets appended to the streak
        });
}
```

**Test program**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var roll in new Program().GenerateRoll(dies: 2, faces: 3, max_generations: 4))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", roll.Select(v => $"G{v.gen} {v.value}")));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

```
G1 1, G1 1
G1 1, G1 2
G1 1, G1 3, G2 1
G1 1, G1 3, G2 2
G1 1, G1 3, G2 3, G3 1
G1 1, G1 3, G2 3, G3 2
G1 2, G1 1
G1 2, G1 2
G1 2, G1 3, G2 1
G1 2, G1 3, G2 2
G1 2, G1 3, G2 3, G3 1
G1 2, G1 3, G2 3, G3 2
G1 3, G1 1, G2 1
G1 3, G1 1, G2 2
G1 3, G1 1, G2 3, G3 1
G1 3, G1 1, G2 3, G3 2
G1 3, G1 2, G2 1
G1 3, G1 2, G2 2
G1 3, G1 2, G2 3, G3 1
G1 3, G1 2, G2 3, G3 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 1, G2 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 1, G2 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 1, G2 3, G3 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 1, G2 3, G3 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 2, G2 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 2, G2 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 2, G2 3, G3 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 2, G2 3, G3 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 1, G3 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 1, G3 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 2, G3 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 2, G3 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 3, G3 1, G3 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 3, G3 1, G3 2
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 3, G3 2, G3 1
G1 3, G1 3, G2 3, G2 3, G3 2, G3 2
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution. The only issue with it is that "1,8", "2,8", ... are not valid outputs, as they would immediately trigger the rolling of an additional die. As with Dmitry's answer, how would you modify your program to track which generation each dice roll belongs to (i.e. first generation are the original dice rolled, second generation are any extra dice rolled as a result of the first generation rolling an 8, etc.)?

Comment: I thought you wanted those states - that's why there was a `Prepend(roll)` there. I updated this to track the generations. Code is still fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks for the updated version. However, the output is missing a couple of lines at the end (with the G3 dice showing a 3), and it is outputting one generation less than what is specified (the example has max_generations set to 4, but only shows outputs down to G3).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's start from the generator *without explosion*, it's quite easy:

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Generator(int faces, int count) {
  int[] state = Enumerable.Repeat(1, count).ToArray();

  do {
    yield return state.ToArray(); // safety : let's return a copy of state

    for (int i = state.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (state[i] == faces)
        state[i] = 1;
      else {
        state[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
  }
  while (!state.All(item => item == 1));
}
```

Now, let's use the generator above to create the generator with explosion:

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Generator(int faces, int count, int extra) {
  IEnumerable<(int[], int)> agenda = Generator(faces, count)
    .Select(state => (state, 0));

  for (bool hasWork = true; hasWork; ) {
    hasWork = false;
    List<(int[], int)> next = new List<(int[], int)>();

    foreach (var state in agenda) {
      int explosions = Math.Min(
        state.Item1.Skip(state.Item2).Count(item => item == faces),
        extra - state.Item1.Length + count);

      if (explosions <= 0)
        yield return state.Item1;
      else 
        foreach (var newState in 
          Generator(faces, explosions).Select(adds => state.Item1.Concat(adds)))
            next.Add((newState.ToArray(), state.Item1.Length));
    }

    agenda = next;
    hasWork = next.Count > 0;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
// 2 dice (3 faces each) with at most 4 explosions (extra dice) allowed
var results = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Generator(3, 2, 4) 
  .Select(item => string.Join(", ", item)));

Console.Write(results);
```

**Outcome:**

```
1, 1          # No explosion
1, 2
2, 1
2, 2
1, 3, 1       # last 3 exploded 
1, 3, 2
2, 3, 1
2, 3, 2
3, 1, 1       # first 3 exploded
3, 1, 2
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 2
3, 3, 1, 1    # both first and last 3 exploded
3, 3, 1, 2
3, 3, 2, 1
3, 3, 2, 2
1, 3, 3, 1    # last 3 exploded, we have 3 which we exploded again
1, 3, 3, 2
2, 3, 3, 1
2, 3, 3, 2
3, 1, 3, 1    # first 3 exploded, we have 3 which we exploded again
3, 1, 3, 2
3, 2, 3, 1
3, 2, 3, 2
3, 3, 1, 3, 1 # both first and last 3 exploded, we have 3 which we exploded again
3, 3, 1, 3, 2
3, 3, 2, 3, 1
3, 3, 2, 3, 2
3, 3, 3, 1, 1
3, 3, 3, 1, 2
3, 3, 3, 2, 1
3, 3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3
3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1
3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
1, 3, 3, 3, 1
1, 3, 3, 3, 2
2, 3, 3, 3, 1
2, 3, 3, 3, 2
3, 1, 3, 3, 1
3, 1, 3, 3, 2
3, 2, 3, 3, 1
3, 2, 3, 3, 2
3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1
3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2
3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3
3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1
3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2
3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3
3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1
3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2
3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1
3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2
3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3
3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1
3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2
3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

**Edit:** If you want to get / track generations (or explosions) you can implement extra methods:

```
private static int[] Explosions(int[] record, int faces, int count) {
  int[] result = new int[record.Length];

  int extra = count;
  int startAt = count;
  int completed = 0;
  int generation = 0;

  while (true) {
    generation += 1;
    int take = extra;

    extra = record
      .Skip(completed)
      .Take(take)
      .Count(item => item == faces);

    if (extra <= 0)
      break;

    for (int i = 0; i < extra; ++i)
      if (startAt + i >= result.Length)
        return result;
      else
        result[startAt + i] = generation;

    startAt += extra;
    completed += take;
  }

  return result;      
}
```

Let's have some readable text:

```
private static String Explain(int[] record, int faces, int count) {
  return string.Join(" then ", record
    .Zip(Explosions(record, faces, count), (item, rank) => new { item, rank})
    .GroupBy(value => value.rank, value => value.item)
    .Select(group => $"explosion #{group.Key} ({string.Join(", ", group)})"));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", 
  new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 })); 
// We have 2 dice with 3 faces each;
// We want to explain 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 sequence
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Explosions(
  new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 }, 3, 2)));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write(Explain(new int[] { 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 }, 3, 2));
```

**Outcome:**

```
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2 # Initial serie
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 # Corresponding explosions (generations)

explosion #0 (3, 3) then explosion #1 (3, 3) then explosion #2 (1, 3) then explosion #3 (2)
```

**Edit 2:** Finally, if you want to restrict not `extra` dice, but `generations` (`0` - initial cast only, at most `1` explosion whatever dice it is etc.):

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Generator(int faces, int count, int generations) {
  IEnumerable<(int[], int, int)> agenda = Generator(faces, count)
    .Select(state => (state, 0, 0));

  for (bool hasWork = true; hasWork;) {
    hasWork = false;
    List<(int[], int, int)> next = new List<(int[], int, int)>();

    foreach (var state in agenda) {
      int explosions = state.Item1.Skip(state.Item2).Count(item => item == faces);

      if (explosions <= 0 || state.Item3 >= generations)
        yield return state.Item1;
      else
        foreach (var newState in
          Generator(faces, explosions).Select(adds => state.Item1.Concat(adds)))
            next.Add((newState.ToArray(), state.Item1.Length, state.Item3 + 1));
    }

    agenda = next;
    hasWork = next.Count > 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. That's a very elegant solution. How would you modify it to track which generation each dice roll belongs to (i.e. first generation are the original dice rolled, second generation are any extra dice rolled as a result of the first generation rolling an 8, etc.)?

Comment: @JimmyTheOne: I've usez *zero based* generations (`0` is the initial case, `1` - 1st explosion etc.). See my edit

Comment: Thanks for the updated version. However, I do not understand the updated outcome (showing the initial series and corresponding explosions), as it does not appear to show the various combinations of possible rolls in the way the original example outcome did.

Comment: @JimmyTheOne: could you, please, provide *counter example(s)* (i.e. combinations that must have appeared but wasn't returned)?

Comment: I have added a full expected sample output. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to clarify.